# Jquery asp.net textbox validation

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I need to validate a textbox using jquery to accept only 5 numeric characters. And it should be a valid number. Not like "00010". It should start with a natural number. The problem I am facing is i have enabled backspace, but after the last character, it does not accept backspace.

My code is:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#txtLoadCode').keydown(function (key) {
            var keycode = (key.which) ? key.which : key.keyCode;
            var code = document.getElementById('<%=txtLoadCode.ClientID%>').value;
            if ((!(keycode==8|| keycode == 46)) && (keycode < 48 || keycode > 57)) {
                return false;
            }
            else {
                //Condition to check textbox contains five numbers or not 
                if (code.length < 5) {
                    return true;
                }
                else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: The problem you have only is it should be start with number right not zero?

Comment: It should not start with number 0 and backspace should be enabled after th elast key pressed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try, allow only `backspace` while the numbers `count` is `5`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#txtLoadCode').keydown(function (key) {
            var keycode = (key.which) ? key.which : key.keyCode;
            var code = document.getElementById('<%=txtLoadCode.ClientID%>').value;
            if ((!(keycode==8|| keycode == 46)) && (keycode < 48 || keycode > 57)) {
                return false;
            }
            else {
                //Condition to check textbox contains five numbers or not 
                if (code.length < 5 || keycode==8) {
                    return true;
                }
                else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6WDF6/)

Comment: @user2124167 Glad to help.! consider it accepted if you feel it solves your problem. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#txtLoadCode").keyup(function(event) {

  if($(this).val().substring(0,1) == 0)
   {
     $(this).val('');
     return false;}
  else
  {
            // Your rest code
  }

  });
```

It will validate first number of usre in

Here is the demo
http://jsbin.com/IJayAzOS/1/

Comment: It is disabling everything in the textbox. I am not able to enter any number

Comment: Any time i am entering a number, it goes in the IF part and clears the text

Comment: if ($(this).val().substring(0, 1) == 0) {
                alert("In key 0");
               $(this).val('');
                return false;
            }
            else {
                var keycode = (key.which) ? key.which : key.keyCode;
                rest code

Comment: Its working :) I had to put all the 0s and 1s in single quote

Comment: if ($(this).val().substring('0', '1') == '0'){ }